# Homework question about basic vector analysis

Tags: problem-solving

Let $\vec{a} ,\vec{b},\vec{c}$ linear Independent vectors that form and ordered basis B. And consider this basis non orthogonal and $\vec{r} = x \vec{a} +y\vec{b}+z\vec{c}$. This vector space is euclidian and Real. 
Prove that:

$\displaystyle x = \frac{\vec{r} \cdot \vec{b}\times\vec{c}}{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}\times\vec{c}}$

Comment: What have you tried? Showing some effort or examples of your own thoughts is a prerequisite on this site. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

$$R=xA+yB+zC$$
Or,$$R.(B×C)=xA.(B×C)+yB.(B×C)+zC.(B×C)$$
Or,$$R.(B×C)=xA.(B×C)$$as other dot products will be zero.

Or,$$x=R.(B×C)/(A.(B×C))$$

Comment: But even in non orthonormal basis? I mean:

$x= \frac{x<a,a>+y<b,a>+z<c,a>}{<a,a>} $